Flask endpoint to Lambda function
I have a bunch of endpoints in a utility Flask application. One endpoint is like this:
@app.route('/Terminal/Velocity', methods=["GET"])
def terminal():
   if request.method != "GET":
      raise Exception("Only GET supported")
   # do some work on request.args and generate a JSON response
   return JSON_ENCODED_RESULT

I want to move this to a lambda, using the serverless framework. I am able to deploy a simple app using sls deploy but I am not sure how to port over this functionality in to a lambda so that somebody can curl to it like
 curl -X GET https://xx-execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Terminal/Velocity?arg1=1000&arg2=2000

